# Level of "pre education"? Equal to intermediate(FA/Fsc)?

Tags: terminology, academic-writing

Actually i am applying for MS in hungry and i am filling online application form, i have attached snapshot,What is the Level of pre education?Does it occurs between 10th grade(class) and university degree(bachelor degree) [image]

Comment: You are applying to study **in Hungary**, not _hungry_! A little online searching suggests that 'pre-education' courses are designed to prepare students for studying to be a teacher.

Comment: @KateBunting  with a citation that would be an answer

Answer (score 2):

A little online searching suggests that 'pre-education' courses are designed to prepare students for studying to be a teacher.

For example: https://dmacc.edu/programs/pdp/education/Pages/welcome.aspx